# Is Stephen Lavavej's Mallocator the same in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, std, allocator

8 years ago, Stephen Lavavej published [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2008/08/28/the-mallocator/) containing a simple allocator implementation, named the "Mallocator". Since then we've transitioned to the era of C++11 (and soon C++17) ... does the new language features and rules affect the Mallocator at all, or is it still relevant as is?

Comment: It's much much simpler now.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Link ? Explanation?

Comment: Maybe look at the allocator example half-way down [this guide](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_example_usage.html) and replace all mentions of "arena" with `malloc`/`free`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: So, no more `construct()`?

Comment: No, `construct` has a default implementation now as part of the allocator traits. You can specify it if you need it to do something non-default (e.g. like `scoped_allocator` does).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

STL himself has an answer to this question in his [STL Features and Implementation techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c) talk at CppCon 2014 (Starting at 26'30).

The [slides](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/STL%20Features%20And%20Implementation%20Techniques/STL%20Features%20And%20Implementation%20Techniques%20-%20Stephan%20T.%20Lavavej%20-%20CppCon%202014.pptx) are on github.

I merged the content of slides 28 and 29 below:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // size_t, malloc, free
#include <new> // bad_alloc, bad_array_new_length
template <class T> struct Mallocator {
  typedef T value_type;
  Mallocator() noexcept { } // default ctor not required
  template <class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept { }
  template <class U> bool operator==(
    const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept { return true; }
  template <class U> bool operator!=(
    const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept { return false; }

  T * allocate(const size_t n) const {
      if (n == 0) { return nullptr; }
      if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T)) {
          throw std::bad_array_new_length();
      }
      void * const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
      if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
      return static_cast<T *>(pv);
  }
  void deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept {
      free(p);
  }
};
```

Note that it handles correctly the possible overflow in allocate.

Comment: should it be `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` rather than `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` though?

Comment: @einpoklum It is guaranteed by the standard to be the same: size_t have to respect mod 2^N arithmetic where N is the number of bits of size_t.

Comment: It's still bad coding IMHO to use the latter rather than the former.

Comment: @einpoklum I Agree.

Comment: @einpoklum I think `std::list` requires other methods of an allocator to be defined like `rebind`.

Answer (score 3):

As @kerrek suggested, here is a Mallocator that is based off the [linked](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_example_usage.html) arena allocator with the arena part deleted.

```
template<class T>
struct Mallocator11 {
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = T*;
  using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::true_type;
  using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
  using propagate_on_container_swap = std::true_type;

  Mallocator11(Mallocator11 const&) = default;
  Mallocator11& operator=(Mallocator11 const&) = default;
  Mallocator11()=default;
  template<class U>
  Mallocator11(Mallocator11<U> const&) noexcept {}
  template<class U>
  Mallocator11& operator=(Mallocator11<U> const&) noexcept {return *this}


  pointer allocate(std::size_t n) {
    if (std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T) < n)
      throw std::bad_array_new_length(); // or something else
    if (!n) return nullptr; // zero means null, not throw
    if(auto*r= static_cast<pointer>(malloc(n * sizeof(T))))
      return r;
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  void deallocate(pointer p, std::size_t n) {
    free(p);
  }
  template<class U>
  bool operator==(Mallocator11<U> const& rhs) const {
    return true;
  }
  template<class U>
  bool operator!=(Mallocator11<U> const& rhs) const {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Lots less code.  Some traits for propogation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about the overflow detection and when it may or may not be needed?

Comment: `allocate` need to throw on error; it can't return null.

Comment: The `friend` declaration and cross-type assignment are extraneous. It would be a good idea to `if (std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T) < n) throw bad_alloc();` in `allocate` to avoid buffer overflows. And what @T.C. said.

Comment: By the way, there's a new `is_always_equal` member predicate now that can perhaps substitute for the POC* traits.

Comment: @KerrekSB Not yet. Some container requirements are still stated in terms of POCMA. Meanwhile, `is_always_equal` is already true for empty allocators.

Comment: @casey there is something different I should throw rather than bad alloc, no?  Going to concert, next edit in hours.

Comment: I think a bad_array_new_length is the correct exception to throw. see my answer and the code from STL himself.

Comment: @Arnaud There really is no required behavior in this case: It's a precondition that `n <= std::allocator_traits<Mallocator11<T>>::max_size()`, which defaults to `std::allocator_traits<Mallocator11<T>>::size_type(-1) / sizeof(T)`. That said, I think both `assert` and `throw` are better ways to handle the precondition violation than allocating a small buffer that may be overflowed. `bad_array_new_length` is a good choice of exception to throw since it's derived from `bad_alloc`; callers that care can distinguish them, callers that don't can ignore the difference.

Comment: @Casey I don't think there is a precondition violation. According to N4527 C++17 draft, There is no precondition to allocate in 17.6.3.5: "Memory is allocated for n
objects of type T but objects
are not constructed. allocate
may raise an appropriate
exception.181[ Note: If n == 0,
the return value is unspecified.
—end note ]"

Comment: @Arnaud The allocator requirements table (table 28 in N4582) says that `a.max_size()` is "The largest value that can be meaningfully passed to `X::allocate()`."

Comment: And ewww "appropriate exception." Could that phrase be any more vague?

Comment: @Casey max_size just indicates the value after which you will get an exception.

Comment: @Arnaud "The largest value that can be meaningfully passed to `allocate`" is not the same thing as "The largest value that can be passed to allocate without causing an exception." The requirements literally say that `allocate(max_size() + 2)` has no meaning.

Comment: @Casey to be fair, if `max_size()` is a `size_t`, and  `max_size()+2` happens to equals`1`, then it has a meaning (`size_t` is mod-2^n for some n).  Not a *useful* meaning, but because `max_size()+2<max_size()` it has a meaning.  Wait, this isn't fair: this is stupidly pedantic.  I knew it was one of the two.  So hard to tell sometimes.  ;)

Comment: It looks like std::size_t(-1) is being used to get the max value for size_t, but if that's what you want, wouldn't std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max be a better fit, and more portable?

Comment: @Elkvis No; size_t is guaranteed unsigned, and unsigned is guaranteed to be math mod `2^n` for some `n`.  Thus `unsigned_type(-1)` is *always* the max value of any unsigned type.  As a slight bonus, it does not require including the standard header file that has `numeric_limits` in it.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, I should have said "When `sizeof(T) > 1`, the requirements literally say that `allocate(max_size() + 2)` has no meaning" ;)